# Correct indentation rules using guards

Tags: haskell, syntax-error, indentation, do-notation, guard-clause

I've looked at questions regarding indentation, which were of no help. My indentation also looks correct but according to the compiler it isnt.
What is the correct indentation and what are the rules?

```hs
readFile filename = do 
                    inputFile <- openFile filename ReadMode
                    readLines inputFile
                    hClose inputFile

readLines inputFile = 
        do endof <- hIsEOF inputFile 
            | endof = return() 
            | otherwise = do 
                          inpStr <- hGetLine inputFile
                          print inpStr
                          readLines inputFile
```

Using all spaces and no tabs.
Error:
"parse error on input '|' 
| endof = return() "

Answer (score 4):

You could restructure your code for this, like

```
readLines :: Handle -> IO ()
readLines inputFile  =  g =<< hIsEOF inputFile
    where                  -- hIsEOF :: Handle -> IO Bool
      g endof
            | endof = return () 
            | otherwise = do 
                          inpStr <- hGetLine inputFile
                          print inpStr
                          readLines inputFile
```

The guards,  `|  ...`, belong to function definitions or case expressions. They can't appear in `do` block by themselves.

`g =<< hIsEOF inputFile` is a shorter way to write

```
readLines inputFile  =  do {  endof <- hIsEOF inputFile
                           ;  g endof
                           }
    where
      g endof
            | endof = .....
```

But a simpler option is just to use `if ... then ... else ...` in the `do` block in the first place:

```
readLines inputFile = 
        do { endof <- hIsEOF inputFile 
           ; if endof 
                then return() 
                else do { inpStr <- hGetLine inputFile
                        ; print inpStr
                        ; readLines inputFile
                        }}
```

Yet another is using [LambdaCase](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=lambdacase#extension-LambdaCase) to inline the `g` definition:

```
readLines :: Handle -> IO ()
readLines inputFile  =  hIsEOF inputFile >>=
    (\ case { True -> return () 
            ; _    -> do 
                          inpStr <- hGetLine inputFile
                          print inpStr
                          readLines inputFile })
```

And case clauses *can have guards* (though here we didn't need them).

Comment: thank you! what is the purpose of "readLines :: Handle -> IO ()" ?

Comment: it is the function's type signature. `readLines` is the function's name, `::` means "has a type of" `A -> B` means "a function from values of type `A` to values of type `B`".

Comment: thanks! is it necessary to declare the signature or just (very) useful?

Comment: the latter . :)

Answer (score 1):

As Will Ness explains in his answer, indentation is not your issue here—the problem is that you’re trying to use a guard (`| …`) after a statement in a `do` block, but guards can only ever appear between patterns and bodies in (1) function equations:

```
function param1 param2
  | guard1 = body1
  | guard2 = body2
  …
```

And (2) `case` expressions:

```
case expr of
  pattern1
    | guard1 -> body1
    | guard2 -> body2
  pattern2
    | guard3 -> body3
  …
```

So you probably want an `if` expression instead. As for the rules of indentation, your code is indented correctly, but you don’t need as much whitespace as you’re using: the basic rules are:

- Certain keywords such as `do`, `let`, `where`, and `of` begin *layout blocks*
- Within those blocks, everything must be indented past the first column of the first line in the block
- If an expression wraps across multiple lines, the lines following the first must be indented

So a rule of thumb that always works is to simply add a newline and indent by some number of spaces (e.g. 2 or 4) after every such keyword:

```
readFile filename = do -- newline+indent to begin block
  inputFile <- openFile filename ReadMode
  readLines inputFile
  hClose inputFile

readLines inputFile = do -- newline+indent to begin block
  endof <- hIsEOF inputFile
  if endof -- indent to continue if expression
    then return () 
    else do -- newline+indent to begin block
      inpStr <- hGetLine inputFile
      print inpStr
      readLines inputFile
```

The alternative style is to start a block on the same line as the layout keyword; then everything needs to have the same alignment as that line:

```
readFile filename = do inputFile <- openFile filename ReadMode
                       readLines inputFile
                       hClose inputFile

readLines inputFile = do endof <- hIsEOF inputFile
                         if endof
                           then return () 
                           else do inpStr <- hGetLine inputFile
                                   print inpStr
                                   readLines inputFile
```

I prefer to avoid this style because it leads to deep indentation, which also depends on the width of the code before it.

Both of these styles are desugared to the following code with explicit delimiters, which you can also write yourself to get a better feel for how layout works:

```
readFile filename = do {
  inputFile <- openFile filename ReadMode;
  readLines inputFile;
  hClose inputFile;
};

readLines inputFile = do {
  endof <- hIsEOF inputFile; 
  if endof
    then return () 
    else do {
      inpStr <- hGetLine inputFile;
      print inpStr;
      readLines inputFile;
    };
};
```

One thing that often trips people up is that `let` also introduces a layout block for defining multiple bindings in the same block. So if you write a `let` statement or `let`…`in`… expression with a long definition, then you need to either write it aligned:

```
let example1 = some very long definition
      that we need to wrap across lines
    example2 = another binding for illustration
--  ^ everything must be aligned past this column
in example1 . example2
```

Or use the same newline+indent style as for everything else:

```
let
  example1 = some very long definition
    that we need to wrap across lines
  example2 = another binding for illustration
in example1 . example2
```

Finally, as a convenience, `if x then return () else y` can be written `unless x y` or `when (not x) y` using `unless` or `when` from `Control.Monad`:

```
import Control.Monad (unless)

…
  endof <- hIsEOF inputFile
  unless endof $ do
    inpStr <- hGetLine inputFile
    print inpStr
    readLines inputFile
```

Furthermore, you may see the `$` omitted before `do` (and other block keywords like `case` and `\`) in code that enables the `BlockArguments` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BlockArguments #-}
import Control.Monad (unless)

…
  endof <- hIsEOF inputFile
  unless endof do -- no need for $
    inpStr <- hGetLine inputFile
    print inpStr
    readLines inputFile
```